# How to reference outer table in a SET sub query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have these tables:

```
create table letter (id_letter bigint, id_group_table bigint, letter char(1));  
create table group_table (id_group_table bigint, id_whatever bigint, champion char(1));
create table whatever (id_whatever bigint);
```

I want to update the `group_table` so I can set in the `champion` column the letter that has most occurrences in the `letter` table that is related with each row from the `group_table`. Today I have to iterate in my application all rows from the `group_table` and run a query for each row to discover what is the letter most used... I want to do that in one update, is it possible?

Here's what I'm trying (and does not work):

```
update group_table gt
    set gt.champion = 
    (
        select inner_champ from 
        (
            select le.letter as inner_champ, count(*) from letter le
            where le.id_group_table = gt.id_group_table
            group by le.letter
            order by count(*) desc
            limit 1
        )
    )
where gt.id_whatever in (1,2,3,4);
```

MySQL does not allow me to reference the `group_table` inside the sub query with `gt.id_group_table`... is it possible to do that?

Thanks!!

Comment: Schema if anybody wants to play with it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82f1fb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update group_table 
join
  (
        select tab1.letter, tab1.id_group_table from 
        (
          select  letter,
          id_group_table, 
          count(letter) as occurrences
          from letter
          group by id_group_table, letter 
          order by occurrences desc
        ) tab1
        group by tab1.id_group_table having max(tab1.occurrences)    

  ) tab2 on group_table.id_group_table = tab2.id_group_table

set champion = tab2.letter
where group_table.id_whatever in (1,2,3,4);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `JOIN` with `group_table` separately in inner query like below

```
update group_table 
join
        (
            select letter,
            id_group_table, 
            count(distinct id_group_table) as occurences
            from letter
            group by letter
            having max(occurences)
        ) tab on group_table.id_group_table = tab.id_group_table
set champion = tab.letter
where group_table.id_whatever in (1,2,3,4);
```

Comment: But this way the sub query is not related with `gt1`. Say the update will update lines 1, 2, 3, 4 from `gt1`. The first iteration from the update, it will update line 1. Say the line 1 has `id_group_table` = 77. How does your sub query, is fetching just what is related with `id_group_table` 77?

Comment: Thanks but I still can't see the relation between the currently update row and the result from the sub query. This way, all rows from `group_table` will be updated, getting the letters with most occurrences inside the `gt.id_whatever in (1,2,3,4)` that does not matter for me. What I really need, is a connection between the currently-being-processed-row-from-update with the letter table..

Comment: I could remove this `where` condition, it doesn't have any relevance for my problem

Comment: You can do a `JOIN` with the inner result set but since your inner query returns only 1 row, didn't do that. Moreover, if there is no WHERE condition, then you meant to update all rows ... right?

Comment: Yes but I think you are missing something: each line in the `group_table` table, has 1 champion. This champion, is the letter that repeated more times in the `letter` table AND is connected with this line. I do not want the most repeated letter... that's easy! I want the most repeated letter, for each line in the `group_table`

Comment: That's what I need, thanks a lot Rahul. I am just not sure that this `having` will work, I'll give it a try when I can and accept your answer! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, it did not work... the subquery returns 0 rows

Comment: Strange! can you create a fiddle (https://www.sqlfiddle.com) with the tables involved in the query along with few sample data. can see then what's wrong.

Comment: Rahul, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82f1fb/2  I put there just your subquery. See that its not giving the expected result that should be B for GT 1, C for GT 2, X for GT 3 and A for GT 4

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a join instead of the where. Try something like that:

```
select inner_champ from 
    (
        select le.letter as inner_champ, count(*) from letter le
        left join group_table gt2 on le.id_group_table = gt2.id_group_table
        group by le.letter
        order by count(*) desc
     )
```

Comment: This sub query will give me all letters grouped, ordered by the amount of occurrences, independently of each row the update will process. I need the sub query to return just one row, related with each row from the update

Comment: ok in that case you can add "Top 1" to the query or may do it like in your first query with the "Limit 1"

Comment: This way I'd get the letter with most occurrences for any `gt` row. I need the letter with most occurrences related only with the row being processed by the update.